# Angular Authorization not working with Laravel Passport Auth API

Tags: angular, laravel, authorization, token, laravel-passport

I have created a laravel API and i am using Passport Auth to authenticate. It working perfectly with postman but i cannot get it to work with Angular 7

I have googled all over and tried several solutions but none works for me

```
CategoriesGet(Url): Observable<Categories> {
    return this.http.get<Categories>(Url, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Token')),
      })
    }).
    pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

getCategories() {
    this.gl.CategoriesGet(this.gl.CategoryUrl).subscribe((rs) => {
      this.catergs = rs.data;
    }, error => {
      Swal.fire('Saving', error.message, 'error');
      console.log(error.message);
    });
  }



 UserLogout(users: Users, Url): Observable<Users> {
    console.log('Bearer Token ' + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('User_Token')));
    return this.http.post<Users>(Url, users, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('User_Token')),
      })
    }).
    pipe(catchError(this.gl.handleError));
  }
```

I really want it to work. I want to perform all my crud operations using Token Authorization that its generated when user logs in

Comment: what error you got?

Comment: Unauthorized. This error from my API